# How to compile memory videos from a shared album?

Tags: icloud, photos, ios

For a normal album, you can just click the three dots at the top right corner of the open album and select "Play Memory Video" to create one and then edit the memory video from there.

The "Play Memory Video" option is, however, missing in the shared albums. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see as of 2022 in iOS 16 is to do the following

1. Create a new normal (unshared) album
2. Add photos from the shared album to the newly created album
3. Create memory video from the new album

One reason why the "Play Memory Video" option may not be available in shared albums is that they are only cached in your phone but reside in iCloud. My guess is that you can only create memory videos of the photos you own and reside in the device.